# undefined method `strftime` for nil:NilClass in chrome & safari but not firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am receviving undefined method `strftime` for nil:NilClass in my index.html. For some reason this error exist in chrome and safari but not in firefox.  Any help would be appreciated. I have the following in my model, controller and view:

user_meetup.rb

```
def self.request(start_date, start_time, location, description)
  transaction do            
    start_time = [start_date, start_time].join(' ').to_time unless start_time.blank?

    meetup1 = UserMeetup.create!(start_time: start_time, location: location, description: description)
    meetup2 = UserMeetup.create!(start_time: start_time, location: location, description: description)
  end
end

def time
  start_time.strftime("%l:%M %P")
end

def date
  start_time.strftime("%B %e,  %Y")
end
```

user_meetups_controller.rb:

```
class UserMeetupsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  respond_to :html, :js

  def index
    @user_meetups = current_user.user_meetups
  end
```

In my view I have the following, meetup.date and meetup.time is where i am getting NoMethodError: undefined method `strftime` for nil:NilClass:

```
<% if current_user.user_meetups.each do |meetup| %>
  <% if meetup.accepted? %>
    <div class="accepted">
      <span class="start-date">scheduled for <%= meetup.date  %> at <%= meetup.time %> at <%= meetup.location %></span>
```

Comment: Looks like you have a meetup without a start time?

Comment: you said `meetup.date` and `meetup.time` works in chrome and safari but not in firefox..i don't understand..the data is rendered by erb template engine on your rails server and plain HTML is sent to the browser and the browser paints the html to it's window..that means the HTML sent to chrome and safari will be the same markup sent to firefox.In short, browsers do not process erb templates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@user_meetups` in your view code to access this data, Rails pass instance variables from the controller to the view all the time.

Take care!

Comment: The list of meetups is being accessed through `current_user` i.e. `current_user.user_meetups` so this isn't the problem here.

Comment: Also don't know if this helps but the meetup.date & meetup.time work in firefox but not in chrome or safari

Answer (score 0):

This line below is wrong

```
 def self.request(start_date,...) do

    start_time = [start_date, start_time].join(' ').to_time unless start_time.blank? # <= This line
    ...
  end
```

When start_time is `nil` or `""`, it would not get assigned.

Since the *variable* start_time is blank, you might be looking for:
        start_time = [start_date, start_time].join(' ').to_time

Generally, I would avoid using an attribute name (used here `[start_date, ...]`) for local variables ( used as `start_date =` )